# Dash plotly Geolocation issue when local hosting with vpn

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, plotly-dash, pihole

I am running a pivpn server on my local network to access my other rpi running my dash app (though app.run_server). The pivpn server also uses pi-hole (on the same rpi) as a dns resolver.

The dash app uses dcc.Geolocation, which turns out is unavailable when not using https. Https is not available when using app.run_server. But works when using app.run() locally on my laptop.

If i got my hands on a ssl certificate, the location of the client would anyways be the same as the pivpn location. since the vpn is masking the location. Is there a way to use dcc.Geolocation on apps hosted on local networks? With vpn or port forwarding? Or do i have to pay for a hosting service? If a hosting service is my only option, any recommendations?